# Vue: Dropdown Menu transition and how to toggle class of another element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, dropdown, transition

I got this (very simplified):

```
<div class="dropdownMenuWrapper">
  <ul class="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdownMenuItem"> Menu 1 </li>
    <button class="arrow" @click="toggleActive">></button>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdownListWrapper">
  <ul class="dropdownList">
    <li class="dropdownItem">DropdownItem</li>
    <li class="dropdownItem">DropdownItem</li>
    <li class="dropdownItem">DropdownItem</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to code a dropdown menu, which opens down with transition. So the height will go from 0 to maybe 100px in a 1s transition.

So I think it's a good way to switch the class of `dropdownList`. Am I right? First it got's the class with height 0 and after the arrow is clicked it got's the class with the higher height.

My Question: How do I switch the class of this with the click event on arrow?

Comment: Add a ref to your template markup or use the querySelector to get your dropdownList node, after you have the element, toggle the class using `element.classList.toggle("dropdownList")`

Answer (score 2):

### Answer:  [Use class binding](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html)

As it is unclear on which Vue version you are using, I will be assuming you are using vue3+.

In your script tag, add a [Ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html) to be referenced in the template section. Since you are only checking if a button is clicked or not, you use Boolean type.

```js
const isActive = ref(false)
```

then use class binding (add a `:` in front of class attribute) to conditionally put the class on the tag based on the value of `isActive` by using [JS Ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```html
<ul :class="isActive ? 'active-dropdown-list' : 'inactive-dropdown-list'">
```

Basically if `isActive` is true, it will put `active-dropdown-list` on that element, otherwise it will be `inactive-dropdown-list`